# Is there a way to find out where the flutter app was created? like in which country ? through any of the files generated by Flutter or Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

I am just curious if there is a way to see in what country a application was created and at what timeby any of the flutter or dart files that are created?

Comment: Nope. No IDE does not save anything.

Answer (score 0):

No dart and flutter file are not save any location or this kind of data.